# How to configure w=1 and j=1 by default

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I would like to confirm my configuration of write concern with majority and journal are correct.

I have three mongodb nodes:

1) In the mongo.conf of all mongodb servers, i added

```
storage:
    journal: enabled: true
```

2) in the mongodb shell, i entered

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.settings.getLastErrorDefaults = {w: 1, j: true}
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Am I correct?

if yes, my second question is, what is the purpose of step 1 for?

Thanks

Comment: What version of MongoDB server and driver are you using? The default write concern only applies when you haven't specified a write concern in your driver/application, so if you want to ensure majority writes you should set this in your application configuration as well. Your value of `w:1` only requests acknowledgement from the primary -- you need  `w:majority` for majority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have done correct steps to configure default write concern settings.

What comes to the second question, as it is written [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) at the documentation:

> WiredTiger uses checkpoints to provide a consistent view of data on disk and allow MongoDB to recover from the last checkpoint. However, if MongoDB exits unexpectedly in between checkpoints, journaling is required to recover information that occurred after the last checkpoint.
>
> With journaling, the recovery process:
>
> 1. Looks in the data files to find the identifier of the last checkpoint.
> 2. Searches in the journal files for the record that matches the
>    identifier of the last checkpoint.
> 3. Apply the operations in the journal files since the last checkpoint.

Comment: Do I still need to add "journal: enabled: true" in the config file on every mongodb? If i have already specified the "j:true" in getLastErrorDefaults, is it good enough as no need to double declaring of it?

Comment: It is good that way.

Comment: @Sury.C The journal is enabled by default, so you do not need to explicitly set this in your config files. The journal allows more frequent writes to disk to mitigate data loss and maintain integrity in the event of unexpected shutdown. Having the journal enabled is different from requesting an acknowledgement that a write has been committed to the journal. Disabling the journal increases the window of potential data loss and will reduce performance if you request `j:true` (which forces a checkpoint/fsync since this is the only on-disk write that can be acknowledged without a journal).